# How to Get Alert When 'A' View Come Out From 'B' View in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have requirement, can I have Alert When,

1)Say 'B' View is Bigger View than 'A'.
2)'A' view is on top of 'B' view.
3)When 'A' view Crosses the Border of 'B' View using PanGesture then We Should get Alert.

Comment: i am adding answer check it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!CGRectContainsRect(B.frame, A.frame))
{
    NSLog(@"ALERT !!!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the target method of your pan gesture check if A view's frame is contained inside B view's frame by using **CGRectContainsRect()** method.

If it returens NO then show your alert.

```
 if(!CGRectContainsRect(B.frame, A.frame)){
    //show alert here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
if (!CGRectContainsRect(B.frame, A.frame))
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"You have crossed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Comment: You have given the answer after 15 min since first answer . Why are you repeating the same one  ?

Comment: I thought he still didn't accept answer. He can accept my answer if he don't wanna write code. Because i've provided full code.

Comment: Nothing new in the alert view code . The main trick here is CGRectContainsRect . That already provided in answer below .

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!CGRectContainsRect(B.frame, A.frame))
{

UIAlertView * alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"..." message:@".." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alert show];


}
```

try this one..

Comment: Jitendra What are you doing?? You are giving same answer after almost 25 mins of the first. Even after seeing the comment on @Dharmbir Choudhary's answer. Until you have a new answer please don't put duplicate at least.

Comment: Remove your answer either or keep it in mind for next time :) Coz it may cause you (-ve) votes